# how to make an entity in ORION?

Tags: fiware-orion

I have some doubts about how to define an Entity in ORION.

This entity will be used to contain GPS, acceleromerer, compass and gyroscope sensor data from smartphones for a specific user. The whole concept is defined as a user session. I will also want to publish when the session "starts" and when it "ends".

Given the high volume expected specially for accelerometers, compass and gyroscope sensors I don't expect to be sending this sensor info every time it happens, but say, probably once the session has finished and all data has been collected in the smartphone. Thus, I see the attributes more as list of values than discrete ones. Thus, putting something like this:

```
{
"contextElements": [
 {
  "type": "UserSession",
  "isPattern": "false",
  "id": "",
  "attributes": [
      {
      "name": "user_id",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "none"
      },
      {
      "name": "app_id",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "none"
      },
      {
      "name": "status",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "none"
      },
      {
      "name": "x_accelerometer",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },

      {
      "name": "y_accelerometer",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "z_accelerometer",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "gps_latitude",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "gps_longitude",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "gps_altitude",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "gps_accuracy",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "gps_heading",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "gps_speed",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "compass",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      },
      {
      "name": "gyroscope",
      "type": "float",
      "value": "0.0"
      }
  ]
  }
  ],
  "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

Not sure if this is the correct way to do it. I don't want to kill the battery of the smartphone sending data every second or even less, so I might be doing that every minute, or so, thus I need a list of values for each the attributes that represent sensor data. Am I right or am I approaching this the wrong way?

In the end, I want to subscribe to these attributes, in another app, and do some reasoning based on the values to create alarms, so I will also probably need an Alarm Entity too.

Thanks!

Comment: I understand that `"id": ""` in only an example. Note that NGSI needs that every entity has an not-empty ID.

Comment: THat's right, is just for clarification purposes, an unique ID will be generated afterwards, same as some of the values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Orion API is quite flexible and allow you multiple posibilities:

- To create/update all the attributes on a given entity in a single request
- To create/update a subset of the attributres of a given entity in a single request. For example, if you entity have 100 atributes, but you only want to update 2 of them (leaving the other 98 untouched) you can do that.
- To create/update atributtes (either all of them or a subset) in several entities in the same request. For example, you can update attributes A and B belonging to entity E1 and attributes C and D belonging to entity E2 in the same request.

If you want to save battery in your client, then maybe the last option is the most suitable. For example, you can hold a buffer in the client with the accumulation of entities changes and flush the buffer each minute sending one updateContext request with the all the accumulated changes.

Comment: @fglana, How would you define a list of values then for an attribute, given the above entity, the gps_latitude for instance, or this above is correct as is?

Comment: Not sure of fully understand the question... Do you mean to define that the value of gps_latitude is a list of items, e.g. lat1, lat2 and lat3 ?

Comment: Nope, that the value of that attribute is a list of a values [45.54, 45.51, 44. 33, ...] so in a single update I can send a lot of values, not just one

Comment: You can use an arbitrary JSON as an attribute value (have a look to this piece of documentation: https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/structured_attribute_valued/index.html), so I think it may suffice your case.